# swift : TableView Cells not getting selected correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView filled with cells from Database, I need to select a cell to edit it. when I select a cell, the indexPath of this cell will be send to a function that I created, this function take that `indexpath` and inject a new cell under the cell I clicked (by adding a new element in array of data at that `indexpath.row`).

Everything works fine when all cells that I have are visible; meaning when there is no scrolling in my `tableView`. but when there is a scroll so there are some hidden down cells, when scroll down fast and select a cell, my function inject a new cell somewhere else and then things start working wrong, and nothing works as expected

The function `getCollCell` get called on click on label in my custom cell:

[image: This my Table]

```
func getCollCell(_ tableViewCellIndexPath:IndexPath,_ collectionViewCellIndexPath:IndexPath)  {
    /// this function that inject new cell
    /// this function get the indexpath of the cell that was clicked from collection of tableViewCell
    /// and indexPath of tableViewCell
    /// tableViewCellIndexPath is indexpath of tableViewCell
    /// collectionViewCellIndexPath is indexPath of collectionViewCell that was clicked  from tableViewCell



    let lignetype = data[tableViewCellIndexPath.row]["st"]!

    let stTypes = [
            Constant.storyBoard.prcplSeul,
            Constant.storyBoard.prcplMenu,
            Constant.storyBoard.tiersAvecSupp,
            ]

    if stTypes.contains(lignetype) {

        setHeightToNormal()

        let tmp_table =  clickedTableCell["tableCell"]



        let tmp_collection =  clickedTableCell["collectionCell"]

        /// save indexPath of last clicked cell of tableViewCell.collection
        clickedTableCell["tableCell"] = tableViewCellIndexPath
        clickedTableCell["collectionCell"] = collectionViewCellIndexPath


    if data?.count == dataT?.count {
     /// this condition means that there is no cell injected (no element is added to data array)
        insertTableRow(tableViewCellIndexPath)
        heighlightCell(tableViewCellIndexPath, tmp_table!, collectionViewCellIndexPath,1)

    }else{

        if tmp_table == tableViewCellIndexPath {

            /// if we are still navigating in the same tableViewcell
            /// clicked tableViewCell is equal to last clicked tableViewCell

            if tmp_collection != collectionViewCellIndexPath {
                /// if we chosed different collectionViewCell in the same tableViewCell

                let index = IndexPath(row:(tmp_table?.row)! + 1, section:(tmp_table?.section)!)
                heightOfCell?[(tmp_table?.row)! + 1] = 150

                heighlightCell(tableViewCellIndexPath, tmp_table!, collectionViewCellIndexPath,1)

                tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .fade)

            }else{

                removeTableRow(tmp_table!)
                heighlightCell(tableViewCellIndexPath, tmp_table!, collectionViewCellIndexPath,2)
            }

        }else{
            /// if we try to open a tableViewCell while other tableViewcell was expanded
            /// we close the expanded tableViewCell and open the new one

            removeAndInsertTableRow(tableViewCellIndexPath, tmp_table!, collectionViewCellIndexPath)
        }

    }
    }

}



    func removeTableRow(_ tableViewCellIndexPath:IndexPath)  {

    dataT?.remove(at: tableViewCellIndexPath.row + 1)
    tableView.deleteRows(at:[IndexPath(row: tableViewCellIndexPath.row + 1, section: tableViewCellIndexPath.section)] , with: .fade)
}

func insertTableRow(_ tableViewCellIndexPath:IndexPath)  {

    dataT?.insert(["":""], at: tableViewCellIndexPath.row + 1)
    heightOfCell?[tableViewCellIndexPath.row + 1] = 150
    tableView.insertRows(at:[IndexPath(row: tableViewCellIndexPath.row + 1, section: tableViewCellIndexPath.section)] , with: .fade)
}

func removeAndInsertTableRow(_ tableViewCellIndexPath:IndexPath,_ tmp_row:IndexPath, _ collectionViewCellIndexPath:IndexPath)  {

    tableView.beginUpdates()

    removeTableRow(tmp_row)

    heighlightCell(tableViewCellIndexPath,tmp_row, collectionViewCellIndexPath ,2)

    insertTableRow(tableViewCellIndexPath)

    heighlightCell(tableViewCellIndexPath,tmp_row, collectionViewCellIndexPath ,3)

    tableView.endUpdates()
}



func heighlightCell(_ tableViewCellIndexPath:IndexPath,_ tmp_row:IndexPath,_ collectionViewCellIndexPath:IndexPath, _ bool:Int){

    if bool == 1 {

        if let tcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: tableViewCellIndexPath) as? TableViewCell{

            for t in tcell.collectionView.visibleCells  {
                t.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#f2f2f2")
            }

            setBGColorOfCell(tableViewCellIndexPath, collectionViewCellIndexPath, "#f2f2f2")
        }else{
            print("tableview return nil")
        }
    }else if bool == 2{
        if let tcell = tableView.cellForRow(at: tmp_row) as? TableViewCell {

            for t in tcell.collectionView.visibleCells  {
                t.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#ffffff")
            }

            setBGColorOfCell(tmp_row, collectionViewCellIndexPath, "#ffffff")
        }else{
            print("tableview return nil")
        }

    } else if bool == 3{

        if tableViewCellIndexPath.row > tmp_row.row {
            heighlightCell(IndexPath(row:tableViewCellIndexPath.row + 1,section:tableViewCellIndexPath.section), tmp_row, collectionViewCellIndexPath, 1)
        }else{
            heighlightCell(tableViewCellIndexPath, tmp_row, collectionViewCellIndexPath, 1)

        }
    }

}

func setBGColorOfCell(_ index:IndexPath, _ indexColl:IndexPath, _ color:String) {

    //let index = IndexPath(row:row, section:0)
    //let indexColl = IndexPath(row:cell, section:0)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! TableViewCell


    let cellcoll = cell.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexColl) as! CollectionViewCell


    cellcoll.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#ffffff")
    cell.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: color)
}
```

If you looked to `heighlightCell` function, at first the app just crushes, but when I added the condition `}else{   print("tableview return nil") }` I started noticing the problem

**Why this behadior? (these images down)**
This happend when I click to add a cell and then click again to remove it 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add your code implementation for better understanding the problem.thanks

Comment: @brahimm - please share some code for better understanding.

Comment: Did you use didSelectRowAtIndexPath to add the new cell?
It seems to be the event fired also when not wanted...
Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're messing with the reuse cell mechanism probably.
On scrolling, the injected ones are not taking part
int the reuse, therefore will not appear when the reuse
will take place again.
Override `prepareForReuse()` in your custom cell class 
and there set the cell to its default mode again (in your
case I'm guessing remove the injection)

Comment: adding to the function `prepareForReuse()`, I added `collectionView.ReloadData`  and it worked like a charm